# What is more efficient? Storing a split string in an array, or calling the split method everytime you need it

Tags: java, arrays, split

What is going to be faster, storing a split string into an array and using this array within my program, or could I call the .split() method on the string whenever I needed an array to iterate through?

```
String main = "1,2,3,4,5,6"; 
String[] array = main.split(",");
```

vs

```
main.split(",");
```

whenever I need to use the input values?

I realise it will be way more readable if I were to store the string in an array. I'd just like to know if the .split() takes more computing time than using an array. Since the split method returns an array containing the split strings.

A simple example(?) loop to go with the question:

```
for (int i = main.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){}
```

vs

```
for (int i = main.split(",") - 1; i >= 0; i--){}
```

Comment: array will be significantly faster than split, especially for longer strings

Comment: I don't think `main.split(",")` works the way you think it does... are you sure the code above compiles?

Comment: The way to think of this: you can never make a computer do anything *faster*, you can only ever make it do less work. Which approach does less work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a trade off, like most such things in programming.  If you split just once and use the array directly from then on, you'll save processing time at the expense of memory.  If you split every time, you'll save memory at the expense of processing time.

One is more time efficient, the other is more space efficient.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the `split()` method returns an array so behind the scenes the `main.split(",")` will iterate every time you call it through `main` String to extract the values. So it's faster to use it only once and use the result.

Comment: Doesn't `split(...)` get called/evaluated once (at init time only)... every iteration evals the condition (and post-increment step) does it not?

Comment: That's a nice observation. I've tested it now and you're right. But the call itself takes time too, right? So there is some time saving .. maybe not noticeable, but it's there and makes the idea of using `split()` once faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to split once and keep the tokens around regardless of the size of the array.  If the resulting array is large, it will be more expensive to split each time.  If it is small, the resultant storage is probably not going to be a factor.

If your worried about storage for a large array, then the last time you split should also be a concern.  To mitigate that, simply assign null to the array when your done and let the garbage collector do its thing.

If I were going to iterate thru an array of tokens, I would probably do it like this.

```
for (String token : main.split(",")) {
    // do some stuff.
}
```

which creates the array once.